# Is there a built-in in-memory, LRU cache for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Is there a built-in in-memory, LRU cache for Silverlight? I can write my own from scratch, but I would rather have one built by the pros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Caching Application Block is included in [Enterprise Library for Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7319).

**InMemoryCache** is in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Silverlight.dll.

```
var cache = new InMemoryCache("cache", 100, 50, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

var item = new object();
cache.Add("key", item, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(1));

var cachedItem = cache.Get("key");
Assert.AreSame(item, cachedItem);

Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
Assert.IsNull(cache.Get("key"));
```